# How can I send an owned box to child task?

Tags: memory, task, rust

```
fn main() {
    let mut i = ~100;
    let (port2, chan2) : (Port<int>, Chan<int>) = stream();
        
    chan2.send(i);
        
    do spawn {               
        let i = port2.recv();
        println(format!("==jcpark== i {:?} \n", i));
    }
}
```

If `let mut i =100`, the above code works. But if `i` is an owned box, it does not work.
Could you let me know how to handle it?

Comment: BTW you rarely need to use `~` for types as small as `int`; it's use outside of a recursive data structure (or when required for a trait object) should be restricted to very large values, for which *actual* benchmarking has shown it to be a performance improvement. In general, `~T` and `T` behave identically, except the former is behind a pointer and always has a destructor. Specifically, they both have the same "owned-ness", which means you don't need a `~` to be able to send it between tasks. (Note that `~[]` and `~str` aren't "real" `~` boxes, and so aren't part of the discussion above.)

Comment: (And in fact, having a `~` doesn't make a value automatically sendable; `~T` is sendable if and only if a plain `T` is sendable.)

Answer (score 3):

You have explicitly defined the type of the stream to be `int`, so you can only send `int`. If you set it to `~int` (by changing the types to `(Port<~int>, Chan<~int>)`, then you will be able to send `~int`.

As it stands, the generic parameters for `stream` are being inferred from the defined types for `port2` and `chan2`; it is in fact possible to infer from the `send` and `recv` calls, so you don't actually need to write `int` or `~int` anywhere.

```
fn main() {
    let i = ~100;
    let (port2, chan2) = stream();
    chan2.send(i);
    do spawn {           
        let i = port2.recv();
        println!("==jcpark== i {:?} \n", i);
    }
}
```